# Update xfce4-mailwatch from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

Is it possible to run a command in the console and trigger an update event for `xfce4-mailwatch`? I am looking for the command-line equivalent of <kbd>right-click</kbd> and then `Update Now`.

Using Xfce `4.12` and `xfce4-mailwatch` `1.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

i dont really know but i think there's no "easy" way to do this, found no api for it. maybe you can ask at https://mail.xfce.org/mailman/listinfo/goodies-dev

another (a little ugly) method is to script your mouse... you can use xdotool for this: http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse

hope this helps a little bit!

Comment: I was hoping for some `xfconf` magic..